# Ensuring that a haskell type A contains a member of type B

Tags: generics, haskell, typeclass, strong-typing, uniplate

Let us look at the following code:

```
transformBi (++"asdasd") [1,2,3,4]
```

Clearly, this code does nothing, but it still compiles fine. I would like to create a new version of transformBi that will not compile if the compiler can prove by the types that it is a no-op. Ideally, this would be done by a typeclass called `Contains`, so that the type of the new `transformBi` will be

```
transformBi :: (Biplate from to, Contains from to) => (to -> to) -> from -> from
```

How do we implement `Contains`?

I am looking for a `Contains` that can be automatically derived, not for something I have to write for every algebraic data type.

Comment: By "will not work", do you mean "does not compile"?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a `Generic` instance for a type, then we can search the type of its generic representation for a certain field. We would like to be able to traverse recursive and mutually recursive types, so we need to:

1. Ensure we don't loop endlessly on recursive types. We need to keep record of the visited types, and stop when we encounter one.
2. Make the type family call lazy enough so that GHC actually *stops* computing when we want it to. Closed type families are only lazy on top-down equation matching (i. e. the computation stops at the first matching equation), so we use a helper for recursion.

Here it is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    TypeOperators,
    TypeFamilies,
    DataKinds,
    ConstraintKinds,
    UndecidableInstances,
    DeriveGeneric,
    DeriveDataTypeable
    #-}

import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data 
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Data

type family Elem (x :: *) (xs :: [*]) :: Bool where
    Elem x '[]       = False
    Elem x (y ': xs) = (x == y) || Elem x xs

type family LazyRec hasVisited vis t x where
    LazyRec True  vis x y = False
    LazyRec False vis x x = True
    LazyRec False vis t x = Contains (t ': vis) (Rep t ()) x

type family Contains (visited :: [*]) (t :: *) (x :: *) :: Bool where
    Contains vis (K1 i c p)    x = LazyRec (Elem c vis) vis c x 
    Contains vis ((:+:) f g p) x = Contains vis (f p) x || Contains vis (g p) x
    Contains vis ((:*:) f g p) x = Contains vis (f p) x || Contains vis (g p) x
    Contains vis ((:.:) f g p) x = Contains vis (f (g p)) x
    Contains vis (M1 i t f p)  x = Contains vis (f p) x
    Contains vis t             x = False
```

Now we can define a shorthand for a `Biplate` that works only when `from` possibly contains a `to` field:

```
type family Biplate' from to where
    Biplate' from to = (Contains '[from] (Rep from ()) to ~ True, Biplate from to)
```

And behold:

```
transformBi' :: Biplate' from to => (to -> to) -> from -> from
transformBi'= transformBi

-- this one typechecks, but it's a no-op.
foo :: [Int]
foo = transformBi (++"foo") ([0..10] :: [Int])

-- type error 
foo' :: [Int]
foo' = transformBi' (++"foo") ([0..10] :: [Int])

-- works as intended
foo'' :: [Int]
foo'' = transformBi' (+(10::Int)) ([0..10] :: [Int])

-- works for recursive/mutually recursive types too
data Foo = Foo Int Bar deriving (Show, Generic, Typeable, Data)
data Bar = Nil | Cons () Foo deriving (Show, Generic, Typeable, Data)

foo''' :: Bar
foo''' = transformBi' (+(10::Int)) (Cons () (Foo 0 Nil))
```

Some notes:

- This only works for `Data.Generic.Uniplate.Data`. In the case of `Uniplate.Direct` we could implement custom `biplate`-s that may or may not visit certain fields, so we can't reason anymore about what's no-op and what's not, which is another reason why this doesn't work there.
- We rely on the consistency of GHC and `uniplate` internals, i. e. we suppose that `uniplate` visits a `to` field iff `Rep` contains a corresponding field. This is a reasonable assumption, but might be broken by bugs beyond our control. Also, we have to change the definition of `Contains` whenever the `Generic` representation API changes. On the other hand, we don't pay any runtime penalty for `Generic`, since we only inspect `Rep` at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` can be an empty type class because it has no methods.  You only supply the instances you need.  For example, in this case, if you have only

```
class Contains from to

instance Contains [a] a
```

your example code won't compile because there's nothing matching `instance Contains [Int] String`.

If you plan to use `Contains` extensively, you could alter the definition to `class Biplate from to => Contains from to` and then you'd only need to specify the `Contains` constraint.

Note that if you have a large universe of nested types, you may need to write a lot of `Contains` instances.

I would expect that you could simply omit `Biplate` instances instead of adding this extra class, however it looks like there's a fairly broad `instance (Data a, Data b, Uniplate b, Typeable a, Typeable b) => Biplate a b` so that won't really work.

Comment: I am looking for a Contains that can be automatically derived, not for something I have to write for every algebraic data type.